# What does the term 'spoon' refer to?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

**Note:** This question is not about the assertion from the Matrix that [*There is no spoon*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dzm8kTIj_0M).

There are *tablespoons* and *teaspoons* which are two different things. However is there a plain *spoon* or does this just refer to any sized *spoon*?

Comment: This is no different, really, than _table knives_, _pocket knives_, _carving knives_, and _filleting knives_, all of which are subtypes of _knives_. I'm not sure what you're asking exactly; do you mean whether _spoon_ in itself is a specific size and type of spoon, or whether it is just a generic term that covers all kinds of spoons? If that is the intended question, the answer is the latter: _spoon_ in itself can refer to any type and size of _spoon_ the context makes plausible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Spoon:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Spoon)
is the generic term from which others, like teaspoon, are derived.

> - A utensil consisting of a small, shallow bowl on a handle, used in preparing, serving, or eating food.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spoon_NOUN%20%2Cteaspoon%2Ctablespoon&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cspoon_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cteaspoon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctablespoon%3B%2Cc0) shows usage of spoon vs teaspoon and tablespoon.

[image: Spoon Ngram]

And according to Etymonline.com  its origin dates back to the 14th century.

> As the word for a type of eating utensil, c.1300 in English (in Old English such a thing might be a metesticca), in this sense supposed to be from Old Norse sponn, which meant "spoon" as well as "chip, tile."
>
> - *The "eating utensil" sense is specific to Middle English and Scandinavian, though Middle Low German spon also meant "wooden spatula."* To be born with a silver spoon in one's mouth is from at least 1719 (Goldsmith, 1765, has: "one man is born with a silver spoon in his mouth, and another with a wooden ladle").

Answer (score 3):

*Teaspoon* and *tablespoon* are not just particular types of spoons but also, in the context of cooking, refer to certain volumes of ingredient. (Approximately 5mL and 15mL-20mL respectively, depending on your country). There is no *spoon* in this sense.

Though people can refer to a *spoonful* this is not a particular amount and would depend on the context as to how much it represents.